# Default outline for every view element on D-PAD TV focus

Tags: android, android-tv

Is it possible to have some kind of default outline for each view/drawable in order to support focus for Android TV users? So far I found that I have to create additional layouts as described in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation#focus-selection)

**BUT** I don't want to create a separate file for each and every view in my design since it's custom and it will require to add

**A LOT** of files, but let's say if it's a default yellow border then I'm totally cool with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a drawable with a colored borderline -

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/light_pink" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

And in the View's setSelected callback -

```
@Override
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    super.setSelected(selected);
    if (selected) {
        mViewLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.view_background_focused));
    } else {
        mViewLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.view_background));
    }
}
```

The view_background file when the view is not focused is the same like the view_background_focused file just with 0 as the stroke width.